# How to print number of Acronyms from the sentences saved in separate .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code, it is printing numbers of questions in the sentences but not the acronym. Please help me find out where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
#number of sentences
questions = 0
#number of acronyms
acronyms = 0
    
#open file File.txt in read mode with name file
with open('file.txt', "r", errors ='ignore') as file:
    text = str(file.read())
    import re

    #print(re.sub("([A-Z]\.*){2,}s?", "", text))
    num_questions = str(text.count('?'))

    #print("Number of sentences found: {}".format(num_sentences))

    # for every line in file
    for line in file:
    # for every word in line
        for word in text.split(' '):
    # if word is all uppercase letters
            if word.isupper():
                acronyms+=1

            # if there is a full stop
            if "?" in word:
                questions += questions
#print number of sentences
print("Number of questions:",num_questions)
#print number of acronyms
print("Number of acronyms:", acronyms)
file.close()
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In this case, that would include posting a small example `file.txt`, together with an expected result and the actual result you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
questions = 0 # number of sentences
acronyms = 0 # number of acronyms

#open file File.txt in read mode with name file
with open('file.txt', "r", errors ='ignore') as file:
    text = str(file.read())
    import re

    #print(re.sub("([A-Z]\.*){2,}s?", "", text))
    num_questions = str(text.count('?'))

    #print("Number of sentences found: {}".format(num_sentences))
    print(text)
    for line in text: # for every line in file
        for word in line.split(' '): # for every word in line
            if word.isupper(): # if word is all uppercase letters
                acronyms+=1

            # if there is a full stop
            if "?" in word:
                questions += questions

print("Number of questions:",num_questions) #print number of sentences
print("Number of acronyms:", acronyms) #print number of acronyms
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's checking every letter instead of every word

Try this...

```
import re

questions = 0 # number of sentences
acronyms = 0 # number of acronyms

#open file File.txt in read mode with name file
with open('file.txt', "r", errors ='ignore') as file:
    text = str(file.readlines())

    #print(re.sub("([A-Z]\.*){2,}s?", "", text))
    num_questions = str(text.count('?'))

    #print("Number of sentences found: {}".format(num_sentences))

    for line in file: # for every line in file
        for word in text.split(' '): # for every word in line
            if word.isupper(): # if word is all uppercase letters
                acronyms+=1

            # if there is a full stop
            if "?" in word:
                questions += questions

print(f"Number of questions: {num_questions}") #print number of sentences
print(f"Number of acronyms: {acronyms}") #print number of acronyms
file.close()
```

Tell me if its not working...

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I tried your solution but still it's showing me the numbers of questions but not the acronyms.